# How to compare today date with another date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to compare old date with today's date but I am not getting output true. Please help me.

```
let today = new Date(); // 2021-02-13T13:28:28.501Z

if ("2020-11-04T08:01:25.698Z" < today){
    console.log("True");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable today is a date object you need to compare it with date object only and then only you will get the desired results

````js
if (new Date() === today ) console.log('true')```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two dates (Date objects) using getTime method

```
console.log(date1.getTime() > date2.getTime())
```

This example prints true if date1 is later than date2

In your case:

```
let today = new Date();
let otherDay = new Date("2020-11-04T08:01:25.698Z");

if (otherDay.getTime() < today.getTime()){
    console.log("True");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string to date first

```
if (new Date("2020-11-04T08:01:25.698Z") < today){
    console.log("True");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let today = new Date(); // 2021-02-13T13:28:28.501Z 
    if (new Date("2020-11-04T08:01:25.698Z") < today)
    {
     console.log("True"); 
    }
```

Convert string to Date object and compare.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an isTodaySameDay function and call it.
check out the snippet code below:

```
const isTodaySameDay = (day) => {
    const today = new Date();
    return day.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() &&
    day.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
    day.getDate() === today.getDate();
};

let yesterday = new Date();

yesterday.setDate(yesterday .getDate() - 1);
console.log(isTodaySameDay(yesterday)); //false

let today = new Date();
console.log(isTodaySameDay(today)); //true
```